# Blackberry HttpConnection Connector.open modes

Tags: blackberry, java-me, httpconnection

This may be a stupid question, however I've never really put much thought into the purpose of a connector mode and just used the default (READ_WRITE). What are the differences between calling Connector.open with its three different modes.

1) `Connector.READ`
2) `Connector.WRITE`
3) `Connector.READ_WRITE` (Really only 1/2 since this is obviously both)

Also, what does the "Set end to end required/desired" mean. I am fairly sure I know but the documentation is hazy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the differences between calling Connector.open with its three different modes.

Obviously you can not write to connection if it's opened with `Connector.READ` and vice versa.

There's also another point, check this: [Maximum number of simultaneous connections](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Maximum-number-of-simultaneous-connections/ta-p/444931). I remember I read somewhere that when you use `Connector.READ_WRITE`, then system uses 2 connection handles versus the only.

> Also, what does the "Set end to end required/desired" mean.

Sorry, not sure what you mean here.

**UPDATE:**

> Also, what does the "Set end to end required/desired" mean.

Check the API for [javax.microedition.io.Connector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html). It was used by all developers before RIM rolled out the `ConnectionFactory` in API 5.0. There is an explanation about end-to-end flag:

```
TLS connections SSL or TLS can be set up in one of two modes:
1. Proxy mode
2. End-to-end mode
```

Comment: Within the connection factory you can "setEndToEndRequired()" and "setEndToEndDesired()". The documentation is wonderfully not helpful with "setEndtoEndDesired()  - Sets the End to End Desired". The purpose of my original question was basically... isn't http basically only useful for an input stream, thus, when would you need to write to an HttpRequest.

Comment: @DFTR: If you do a `POST`, then you need to open an `OutputStream` from the `HttpConnection`. I believe (not tested) with just `Connector.READ` you'll not be able to use the `OutputStream`.

Comment: @DFTR: added UPDATE section as to end-to-end.

Comment: That website you linked was perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For example if u perform file operation.Connector.READ- is used to only read from file,Connector.WRITE-is used to write to file,Connector.READ_WRITE-is used read as well as write into file.